# Eclipse shows errors at project but I can't find them

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to run my project but eclipse is saying I have errors but there are no errors just a red cross where the project name is.i tried cleaning the maven project.below are the issue.

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building E2Eproject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ E2Eproject ---
    [INFO] Deleting C:\Users\DTMLLUAdminUser\E2Eproject\target
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.856 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-11T14:42:55-08:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/155M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project E2Eproject: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\DTMLLUAdminUser\E2Eproject\target\test-classes -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please `enter code here`read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to delete
>   C:\Users\DTMLLUAdminUser\E2Eproject\target\test-classes

This is usually due to the files inside the target folder being locked due to the application still running (either in cmd, eclipse or web browser)

Some things to try:

1. Stop the application if it's running in eclipse
2. Terminate the application using ctrl+c if it's running in a command prompt
3. Close any browsers where the application is running
4. If you already closed the web browser, go to Task Manager and make sure there's none running in the background

Once you've completed all of the above, try to `mvn clean` the project again

If you still see the same exception, try restarting your computer. This will guarantee the lock on the target folder is removed and you should be able to clean the project again

Comment: Working fine after restarting the system and cleaning the project.Thank you.

Comment: Yep --- that would have been suggestion #5. The issue is that the target folder was locked due to it being open in some process